# Is there a way to set the entity expansion limit in woodstox?

Tags: java, xml, stax, fasterxml, woodstox

woodstox library has the limit of 100,000 expansions by default. Is there a way to configure that to lower level (say 1000)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. I have been planning to write a blog entry about this (so far only gotten https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/configuring-woodstox-xml-parser-basic-stax-properties-39bdf88c18ec done), but the setting is via `XMLInputFactory.setProperty()`, for key found from `WstxInputProperties` -- specifically I think `P_MAX_ENTITY_COUNT`.

Comment: thanks a lot @StaxMan, that solved the problem. I've checked the properties available on WstxInputProperties but guess I missed it. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad you found it! There is now also third part that actually covers this setting: https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/configuring-woodstox-xml-parser-woodstox-specific-properties-1ce5030a5173